# Can we replicate postgres Data between two OS?

Tags: database, windows, postgresql, ubuntu, database-replication

I want to replicate postgresql data of windows server to linux server, I know how to replication between same operating systems but that method is not working with windows and linux. If yes what would be the better way to do this?

Comment: [Logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logical-replication.html)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use streaming replication between different operating systems.

Look [at the PostgreSQL Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Replication) for a list of replication solutions. Some of them should work for you.

From PostgreSQL v10 on, you could consider [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logical-replication.html).

Comment: Can streaming replication be used between Linux and MacOS?
Can you look into this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777410/postgresql-streaming-replication-slow-on-macos

Comment: No, you cannot replicate between different OS. I cannot help with the linked problem, because I don't use MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

Done this using Postgresql 9.5.21 as master on `Windows 2012 R2` and slave on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

You have to take care about a few things:

- most similar CPU (page size, architecture, registers). So, you can't mix 64/32bit, or using CPU with different endianess or page size;

  - same endianess also for the O.S.: both 32 or 64 bit;
  - same major version of PG: 9.5.x with same or other 9.5.x version (that's for streaming replication, that I'm using, Logical Replication works with different versions of PG);

  So, I find an already installed PG on Windows Server. Edit `postgresql.conf` to enable replica and PITR, and `pg_hba.conf` to allow connection.

  Then moved on Ubuntu and, with PG stopped, I fetched from the master with:

  `pg_basebackup -D /tmp/db/ -X stream -R -U postgres -h ip-master`

  Then modified configuration and replaced data directory with `/tmp/db`.

  Start slave, and is up and running, but look at this:

  > 2020-03-18 21:05:31.598 CET [44640] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read
  >   only connections
  >
  > 2020-03-18 21:05:31.631 CET [44645] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 36/C2000000 on timeline 1
  >
  > 2020-03-18 21:05:31.905 CET [44646] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
  >
  > 2020-03-18 21:05:32.416 CET [44649] postgres@postgres FATAL:  database locale is incompatible with operating system
  >
  > 2020-03-18 21:05:32.416 CET [44649] postgres@postgres DETAIL:  The database was initialized with LC_COLLATE "Italian_Italy.1252",  which is not recognized by setlocale().
  >
  > 2020-03-18 21:05:32.416 CET [44649] postgres@postgres HINT:  Recreate the database with another locale or install the missing locale.

  Here's the funny thing: replication works, but you can't connect to the databases.

  Anyway, if you raw copy the data dir on Windows, it works like a charm.

  Of course, if you re-create the cluster with UTF-8, there's no problem at all.

n.b.: thanks a lot to `incognito` and `ilmari` on official IRC PG channel for the hints.